# Excel remove duplicate and record the line number that have been deleted

Tags: excel, vba

Column E

1

2

3

4

5

5

```
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Range("E1").End(xlDown)
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

I want to remove all duplicate data in column E, but after delete it, I want to record which line have I deleted such as( line 6 has been deleted ) in the other worksheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a new index column (type 1,2,3 then highlight and drag down to create row numbers). Then when deleting duplicates from the other column, expand the range to include both columns. Then use something like the below on the index column to identify the missing numbers

https://www.get-digital-help.com/identify-missing-values-in-a-column-using-excel-formula/

Comment: Hi Marci,  I think this will not work in my real cases because my real data is a big number without continuous.

Comment: You would create a new column with the continuous numbers, then delete from the column with the big numbers and expand the range to delete from both columns